# Return type of Function with Parameters

Tags: python, casting, return-type

```
def add(num1:int,num2:int ) -> str:
    num3 = num1+num2
    return num3
num1 , num2 = 5,6
ans = add(num1,num2)
print(type(ans))
print(f"Addition of {num1} and {num2} is {ans}")
```

I was expecting to return type(ans) as string class.It is happening when i write 3rd line as
return str(num3).In Geeks for geeks(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-functions/) i have seen syntax as
def function_name(parameter: data_type) -> return_type:
why the code is not returning to string class as i wrote return type as 'str'
Is typecasting not possible here?

Comment: Python doesn't do automatic conversions based on the type hints. If you declare that the function returns `str`, it's your responsibility to ensure that it does. Type hints are for use by static type checkers like `mypy` -- it will warn you that you forgot to do the conversion.

Comment: Brother type hints are only for our reference

Comment: Python is strongly typed, no casts happen if you don't cast explicitly. Type hints are just that hints, they don't enforce anything.